# Adding specified value to a check-box list while binding a set of data's

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datasource, checkboxlist

Am binding a set of values into a Check box list through Linq-To-Sql concept,by giving data source and data bind,but with those values i need to also bind a value **"Other"**.
Is there any way to bind ..??

The DataSource which i have given to the Checkbox List,

```
ddlcustom2.DataTextField = "SUB";
ddlcustom2.DataValueField = "CLASS";
ddlcustom2.DataSource = _lst;
ddlcustom2.DataBind();
```

where **_lst** has a set of records,and its the source which i have given to the Checkbox List.

```
ddlcustom2.Items.Add(new ListItem("None", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
ddlcustom2.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("None", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
ddlcustom2.Items.Add("None");
```

And i also tried these stuffs.additional to the list of values i need to also bind **"NONE"** to the checkbox list .is it possible..??

Answer (score 0):

**make sure that you have configured AppendedDataboundItems=true in Drop downlist**

Or

You just need to add None record in _lst before binding to drop down list.

```
_lst.Add ( new classname { "None","000000"} );

ddlcustom2.DataTextField = "SUB";
ddlcustom2.DataValueField = "CLASS";
ddlcustom2.DataSource = _lst;
ddlcustom2.DataBind();
```